# Hilt Not Syncing

Tags: java, android, groovy, dagger-hilt

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions I've seen seems to work for me. I am new to hilt and I am trying to learn it while using java in android studio. I went to android docs and copy/pasted the dependencies, plugins, and class paths that they provide. But when I try to sync the project fails and says this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
```

This is my Top level build gradle:

```
       // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my app level build gradel:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

    }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blogs"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.+"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I changed:

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
        apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    
        }
```

to:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

}
```

but this fails and says:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method kapt() for arguments [com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.28-alpha] on 
object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I then saw a solution which said to use  annotationProcessor instead of kapt in the dependencies for the "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.28-alpha" dependency. I get:

```
 A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Configuration with name 'kapt' not found.
   > The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler dependency was found.
```

and when I use implementation the same thing happens.

Please help me solve this problem and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.

I needed to change:

```
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.28-alpha"
```

to:

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
```

The first one is what I got from the android docs here https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#java

I found this solution here https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2086.